# Erro ao criar um objeto do tipo JSONObject

Tags: java, json

Estou tentando criar um `WebService` que me retorne um ou mais dados do Banco de dados, utilizando como retorno o `JSON`.

```
@Path("teste")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject teste() {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("teste", "teste 1");
    obj.put("teste2", "teste 2");

    return obj;

}
```

Porém quando executo através da URL, ocorre o seguinte erro *(Peguei só apenas as primeiras linhas):*

> ```
>  GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [/TrabalhoWeb1] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException] with root cause
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
> ```

E quando realizo o *debug*, o erro ocorre quando ele vai instanciar o objeto `JSONObject`.

Não faço ideia do que fazer.

Comment: Ta lembrando de importar a classe do objeto do json ?

Comment: @FelipeDM Sim sim, O problema era com a própria biblioteca **JSON_lib**, troquei para a **GSon** da google.